# UNDERSTANDING THE FORMULA in the worksheet

Tags: excel-formula

May I know what is the meaning of this formula used in one of my worksheet:

```
=IF(COUNTA(INDIRECT(F3))-3<0,1,COUNTA(INDIRECT(F3))-3)
```

Answer (score 1):

[INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)(F3) takes the contents of cell F3 and uses it as a Range value.

[COUNTA](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTA-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509) counts the number of non-empty cells in the range

The [IF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function evaluates the boolean expression in the first parameter. If it evaluates to True, it returns the result of the expression in the second parameter. If the first paramater evaluates to False,

So this formula looks at the range specified in F3 and counts the number of cells that are not empty. If that count minus 3 is less than 0 then it returns 1. Otherwise it returns the count minus 3.